# Cartesian product, Could you check me answer?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would love to know if my answer to the following question is correct, this feels weird to me, because the statement of the question sounds very correct and intuitive, but if you don't consider a special case you get it wrong. This is the question:

$$A {\times}B \sqsubseteq C {\times}D \leftrightarrow (A\sqsubseteq C, B\sqsubseteq D)$$ 
The special case is when one of the groups is $\emptyset$, For example: 
$$A=\emptyset, B=\mathbb{N}, C=\{1\}, D=\{2\}$$. 
In that case, The statement on the left holds but the statement on the right is false, because $B\sqsubseteq D$ does not hold. 
Could someone please tell me if I'm right or wrong?

Comment: Absolutely, you need to assume that neither $A$ nor $B$ is empty. Equivalentely, you need only assume $A\times B$ is not empty.

Comment: Does $\sqsubseteq$ mean anything special, or is it the same as $\subseteq$?

Comment: @Arthur same thing, I just don't know how to write the "circle" shape of this in LaTeX...

Comment: Well, $\sqsubseteq$ is a square subset-or-equal relation symbol, with the command `\sqsubseteq`. Given that the commands are invented by humans who try to inject at least some sense into the command names, it's not difficult to at least try `\subseteq`. Similarily, `\subset` without the `eq` gives $\subset$ without the equals line, while `\subsetneq` gives $\subsetneq$, a subset-not-equal symbol. TeX commands do not always make this much sense, but it's nice when they do. By the way, any of these symbols may be flipped by changing `subset` to `supset` (as in superset, the opposite of subset).

Comment: @Arthur Good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The given implication holds under the assumption that sets there are non-empty but not when empty set is involved.